# TIMESTAMPDIFF with clauses

Tags: php, mysql

I have a little problem with a MySQL query:

Table is something like this

```
id  timedate            user  action
1   2010-01-01 10:01:01 AB991 login
2   2010-01-01 12:01:01 AB991 logout
3   2010-01-01 14:01:01 AB991 login
4   2010-01-01 18:01:01 AB991 logout
5   2010-01-01 10:01:01 ZM991 login
6   2010-01-01 10:01:01 ZM991 logout
7   2010-01-02 10:01:01 AB991 login
8   2010-01-02 18:01:01 AB991 logout
9   2010-01-02 10:01:01 ZM991 login
```

Now, I need a query, or some PHP code, to calculate day by day, for each user the difference in minutes between login and logout.
But there can be some problems, like:

1. It is possible that there isn't a logout logged
2. It is possible that for a day I have 2 login and 2 logout actions or more.

There is smart solution (maybe only MySQL) or I must use PHP and make a wall of code?

Comment: What is the query you already tried?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is as follows:

```
select id, timedate, action
from mytable
where user = 'AB991'
order by timedate
```

Your PHP code will get an ordered list by date. The algorithm should look like this:

```
$user = 'AB991';
$stmt = $db->prepare("select id, timedate, action from mytable where user = ? order by timedate");
$stmt->execute(array($user));
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$previousTime = "";
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    if ($row["action"] === "login") {
        $previousTime = strtotime($row["timedate"]);
    } else if ($row["action"] === "logout") {
        if ($previousTime === "") {
            //duplicate logout
        } else {
            //add the remaining time to the day when the user logged in
            //add the whole days passed between log in and log out
            //add the start of the last day when the user logged in
            $previousTime = "";
        }
    }
}
```

**Problems**:

- user might log in with different sessions separately
- user might not log out
- user might log out with a different session

**Suggestion**: I would modify the table to contain a session id and the last action. When a user performs an action, the timestamp of the last action would be updated, so you would have a session-based data, where each row would speak for themselves, showing login time and last action time.

Comment: This is what i've already tried by myself, but with a lot of problem.
Tomorrow i will try your code, maybe is cleaner than mine.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this solution gone help. as base every login flowed by logout To explain the code here 
I join all login records (ranked) with all logout records (ranked)
so if one login will count 1 and if flowed by logout count 1, then will be selected

```
select
logIn. *, logOut.* ,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, logIn.timedate, logOut.timeDate) as howLongUserStaysInMinutes

from (SELECT @row_counter1 := 0) x,
     (SELECT @row_counter2 := 0) y,
     (select userLogs.* , @row_counter1 := @row_counter1 +1 as row 
      from userLogs 
      where userLogs.action ='login') as logIn

 left join (select * ,   @row_counter2 :=  @row_counter2 + 1 as row 
             from  userLogs 
             where  userLogs.action = 'logout') as logOut 
             on  logOut.user = logIn.user
             and ( logIn.timedate <= logOut.timedate ||   logOut.timedate is null) 
             and logIn.row = logOut.row
```

I made change join from inner to left so I one login and did not logout and from row number to rank by day so each day will count login/logout starts from 1 , I used to do this with Microsoft SQL Server.
let's start to explain how query work first data I need
but first you need to be ready for steps to think as following :
 A.I need data ('logout records' and 'login records') <- here you can apply logic for select on per day or max value or same value 
 B.Then I want to apply conditions to get this data and filter it correctly <- here done join login and logout records so you can match them correctly

1.I want to get all login action for each user and give every row a number using variable `@row_counter` and increment 1 for each row

```
  select id, 
         timedate as timedate, # here you can use max() to get max login in day
         user,
         action, # action will be login since it specified at where clause
         @row_counter1 := if(@perv_day1 <> DAY( userLogs.timedate ) , 1 , @row_counter1 +1) rankedByDay
        ,@perv_day1 := if(@perv_day1 <> DAY( userLogs.timedate ) , DAY( userLogs.timedate ) ,  @perv_day1) _day
  from userLogs,
       (select  @row_counter1 :=0) x # here I define the row with 0
       (select @perv_day1 :=0) y # to track rank for each row 
  where userLogs.action ='login'
  group by user # here i group each user
          , DAY( userLogs.timedate ) # also you can group by day
```

out:

```
id  timedate            user    action  rowRankedByDay
1   2010-01-01 10:01:01 AB991   login   1
3   2010-01-01 14:01:01 AB991   login   2
5   2010-01-01 10:01:01 ZM991   login   3
7   2010-01-02 10:01:01 AB991   login   1
9   2010-01-02 10:01:01 ZM991   login   2
```

2.I do the same with the logout actions

```
  select id, 
         timedate as timedate, # here you can use max() to get max login in day
         user,
         action, # action will be logout since it specified at where clause
         @row_counter2 := if(@perv_day2 <> DAY( userLogs.timedate ) , 1 , @row_counter1 +1) rankedByDay,
         @perv_day1 := if(@perv_day1 <> DAY( userLogs.timedate ) , DAY( userLogs.timedate ) ,  @perv_day1) _day
  from userLogs , 
       (select  @row_counter2 :=0) y # here I define the row with 0
       (select @perv_day2 :=0) y # to track rank for each row 
  where userLogs.action ='logout'
  group by user # here i group each user
```

out

```
id  timedate            user    action  rowRankedByDay
2   2010-01-01 12:01:01 AB991   logout  1
4   2010-01-01 18:01:01 AB991   logout  2
6   2010-01-01 10:01:01 ZM991   logout  3
8   2010-01-02 18:01:01 AB991   logout  1
```

Now I have the data, I want to join them so I can find the differences of time but what are to conditions needed to do so,

```
select TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, logIn.timedate, logOut.timeDate) as howLongUserStaysInMinutes
from logIn
left join logOut on (logOut.user =  logIn.user) # same user
              and DAY( logIn.timedate )  =  DAY( logOut.timedate ) # action at the same day
              and logIn.rowRankedByDay= logOut.rowRankedByDay # login and logout actions rows
              and ( logIn.timedate <= logOut.timedate ||   logOut.timedate is null) # login was before logout or user did not logout
```

Sorry if this get more code here, ;) I hope this help you.

Comment: Uhm, it's pretty hard for me to understand all your code, but tomorrow i will try and i will let you know if it works. Thanks!

Comment: ok, there is a little problem that i don't know how to manage in this query, 
the result is making the difference between the first login (ex. 2016-01-15 11:39:35) and first logout (ex. 2016-01-22 11:25:33).
I need to calculate the difference only if they are in the same day.
(I can do the query even day by day).
Any help?

Comment: Another problem, if i have 2 login and 1 logout in the same day, the query must take the highest value and discard the other. (ex. 2016-01-25 11:02:54 -> login | 2016-01-25 14:08:49 -> login | 2016-01-25 14:09:19 -> logout) (I need the difference between the second login and the logout)
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, but now the question is: how i put all that code in a single query? I cannot create views cause it contains variables.
I've maked 3 query separately and I have N rows with NULL as result.
Question: there is a way I can send you the table of the real DB?
Thanks!

Comment: Ok found the error, in the logout query rankedbyday is always NULL, now i search the cause.